# spring boot component bean validation @Positive not working but @NotNull works fine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I have a service managed by spring, I put @Validated annotation on that service refer to [this](https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/#validated-and-valid) article, it tells that spring will do the validation for us, we don't even need to valid it manually.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import javax.validation.Valid;
@Component
@Validated
public class MyService {
    public void execute(@Valid MyRequest request) {
            //todo
    }
}
```

MyRequest is a DTO which will be validated by spring

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.validation.constraints.Positive;

@Data
public class MyRequest {
    @Positive(message = "id should be positive")
    private Long id;
}
```

here is my controller, in some reason, I don't want to do the validation in controller.

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/execute", method = {GET, POST})
    @ResponseBody
    public MyResponse execute() {
        MyResponse res = new MyResponse();
        service.execute(new MyRequest());
        res.setHtmlText("hello world");
        return res;
    }
}
```

when I visit the url: http://localhost:8001/execute
it doesn't give me any exception and show the result hello world

here is the maven dependency

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.fudy</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

however after I replace @Positive to @NotNull, it works fine

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Positive;

@Data
public class MyRequest {
    //@Positive(message = "id should be positive")
    @NotNull(message = "id should not be null")
    private Long id;
}
```

Comment: The `@Positive` will only work when there is an actual value, `null` isn't a value and will be ignored and thus ok. You need both `@NotNull` and `@Positive` or write your own validator.

Comment: yes, finally I find the source code , null is valid for @Positive annotation. see org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.number.sign.PositiveValidatorForLong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works as it should. The validator associated with `@Positive`, the [`PositiveValidatorForLong`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/main/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/bv/number/sign/PositiveValidatorForLong.java#L25) accepts `null` values as valid. So it will only validate actual values, not `null`.

Basically you need them both to fullfil your requirements, so both `@Positive` and `@NotNull` to only allow positive values.

**pro-tip:** As you already have the `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency you don't need the additional `validation-api` and `hibernate-validator` dependencies, those are added already.

Comment: I spend a day lokking for this answer :)